# How to display data in flask from post request on localhost? Error: local variable 'reqData' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I want to display data that im sending in post request in the web browser on localhost:5000/event. In line print (reqData) data is displayed correctly in terminal when server is running, but server is rendering '/event' before i send a post and so reqData is not defined for that site.

post code

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'name': 'asd', 'sname': 'dsa'}

g = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/event', headers=headers, json=payload)


print(g.json)
```

flask code

```
@app.route('/event', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def response():
    if request.method=='POST':
        reqData = request.get_json()
        print(reqData)
        return reqData
    else:
        if(reqData):
            return reqData
        else:
            return 'No request.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your post flask code by :

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'name': 'asd', 'sname': 'dsa'}

g = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/event', headers=headers, json=payload)

print(g.json()) # Line changed
```

Edit :

```
@app.route('/event', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def response():
    if request.method=='POST':
        reqData = request.get_json()
        print(reqData)
        return reqData
    else:
        try: # Adding try except works
            if(reqData):
                return reqData
        except:
            return 'No request.'
```

Comment: Ok but i don't need to print this in 'post' console :/ i want to display that data on '/event'.